# favicon.ico not found when using Areas in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

When I add "areas" route mapping, the browser's request to /favicon.ico which is in the root of wwwroot folder is returning the error: "The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Areas/favicon.ico/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"

No error prior to adding the "areas" endpoint route mapping.

```
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseStatusCodePages();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "areas",
            pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

It looks like the routing engine is confusing favicon.ico for a controller. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move the `UseStaticFiles()` *above* the `UseRouting()` call.

Since middleware executes from top to bottom, in your case `UseRouting` is called first. When the `UseRouting` middleware executes, it determines the route to call based on the endpoint mappings that you passed to `UseEndpoints`. So it sees the route `/favicon.ico` and tries to match it with one of your MVC routes ultimately picking `favicon.ico` as the name of an area (so the full route would have been `/favicon.ico/Home/Index`. And for that, ASP.NET Core obviously cannot find a matching view.

But what you want to do instead is have the static files middleware execute first so that it serves all the static files it can find *before* it attempts to parse the remaining routes as MVC routes.

So just move the `UseStaticFiles()` call up:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

You might also want to move the static files before authentication to make sure thtat all users can also access your static files.